# C# Visualbasic Inputbox

Tags: c#, input

I am using an input box like this

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string host = "localhost";
        Interaction.InputBox("Database Information", "Host", host);
    }
```

It is perfect but how can I update the string host with the new typed text when clicking ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string host = "localhost";
    host = Interaction.InputBox("Database Information", "Host", host);
}
```